# SmartTable How to use setIgnoredFields method

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to update a SmartTable to disable column rendering and table personalization for selected columns using the `setIgnoredFields` method from the API.

However, after accessing the control instance and using the above method, following error is displayed in the console:

> Property `ignoredFields` cannot be changed after the SmartTable with id `"idListReport"` is initialised.

How do we access the SmartTable control instance (before it's initialization?) and use this method so that certain columns can be hidden in table display and personalization?

(Tried this in the `onBeforeRendering` method in the view - however, the control seems to be already initialized by then.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to set it dynamically?
If not, please use

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="idListReport" ignoredFields="a, b, c"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used setIgnoredFields method in View Initialization instead of onBeforeRendering and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dynamically then use this in init method sap.ui.getCore().byId("#tableid").setIgnoredFields("property1,property2,...");